# How to set WCF Tracing to long only Warnings, Erros and Fatals?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, trace

I'm trying to set the Tracing in my WCF server in production, so it logs only "issues". Not information. I looked at Microsoft docs, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/recommended-settings-for-tracing-and-message-logging), but it doesn't work for me.

There is **Recommended Settings for Deployment or Debugging**

I've tried that, and looks like it works. I'm getting every message logged (I think).

There's also **Recommended Settings for a Production Environment**, here:

```
<configuration>  
 <system.diagnostics>  
  <sources>  
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"  
            switchValue="Warning"  
            propagateActivity="true" >  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="xml"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
    <source name="myUserTraceSource"  
            switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="xml"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
  </sources>  
  <sharedListeners>  
    <add name="xml"  
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"  
               initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />  
  </sharedListeners>  
 </system.diagnostics>  

<system.serviceModel>  
  <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">  
  </diagnostics>  
 </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

I pasted it to my config file and.. there is a typo I think. They wrote:

`switchValue="Warning"` (with that the log is not created)

So I changed it to: `switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"`
Now I'm getting the log, but.. I'm getting the same results as with the Debugging version. **Why?**

I was trying:

1)

```
<diagnostics>  
  <messageLogging   
       logEntireMessage="false"   
       logMalformedMessages="false"  
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"   
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"  
       maxMessagesToLog="5" />  
</diagnostics>
```

2)

```
  <sources>  
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"  
            switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing"  
            propagateActivity="true" >  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="xml"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
    <source name="myUserTraceSource"  
            switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="xml"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
  </sources>  
  </sources>
```

3)

```
  <system.diagnostics>  
  <sources>  
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"  
            switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing"  
            propagateActivity="true" >  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="TraceLog"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>   
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
            switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing" 
            propagateActivity="true">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="xml"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>      
    <source name="myUserTraceSource"  
            switchValue="Off, ActivityTracing">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="TraceLog"/>  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
  </sources>  
  <sharedListeners>  
    <add name="TraceLog"  
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"  
                initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />  
  </sharedListeners>  
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Didn't work://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF tracing is built on top of System.Diagnostics and every WCF assembly emits different Trace messages. **System.ServiceModel** is the most common WCF trace source and it emits traces for most of the WCF activities. The level of information emitted is controlled via the **switchValue** attribute in the config files.

You are seeing the start/stop/transfer trace messages also because the **ActivityTracing** trace level is added to the switchValue. If you leave only Warning it should work just fine.

Sometimes the svclog file generated might look empty when the service's host is running (for example if hosted under IISExpress). Stop the site and you'll see the messages generated only for warnings & above.

For example, the diagnostic config below captured only the ArgumentNullException

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="false" name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Warning">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="None">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

[image]

[Configuring Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) doc from MS lists different Trace Levels that can be used with trace sources.